# Run JS MediaQuery on initial load AND on change

Tags: javascript, media-queries, width

I want to load a specific JavaScript snippet only for screen sizes with a minimum width of 1001px to speed up loading time for smaller devices.
Therefore I used the MediaQuery feature to identify the min-width and react on a change like this:

```
            const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1001px)');
            mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                if (event.matches) var t = (0, s.qs)(".js-twitter-feed");
                if ("undefined" != typeof twitterFeed && t) {
                    t.classList.remove("u-hide");
                    var r = document.createElement("div");
                    r.innerHTML = '<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/'.concat(twitterFeed, '">Tweets by ').concat(twitterFeed, "</a>"), t.appendChild(r), (0, o.loadScript)("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js")
                }
            });
```

The problem with this snippet is, that it is only loading the included Twitter widget when a screen size change was performed once and not already when the page is loading and min-width 1001px is true already.
That is why I searched for another solution which looks like this:

```
if (matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1001px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {

    var t = (0, s.qs)(".js-twitter-feed");
                        if ("undefined" != typeof twitterFeed && t) {
                            t.classList.remove("u-hide");
                            var r = document.createElement("div");
                            r.innerHTML = '<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/'.concat(twitterFeed, '">Tweets by ').concat(twitterFeed, "</a>"), t.appendChild(r), (0, o.loadScript)("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js")
                        }
}
```

This code loads the Twitter widget also for screen sizes with a width of less than 1001px.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a function to test the media query, which you shall call once on document load and also add as a handler for the mediaQuery change event. Here is a working sample code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>

function run()
{
    const contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1001px)");
    function onMediaQueryChange()
    {
        if(mediaQuery.matches) contentDiv.innerHTML = "LARGE";
        else contentDiv.innerHTML = "small";
    }

    // will react on later changes
    mediaQuery.onchange = onMediaQueryChange;

    // will handle the initial browser window size
    onMediaQueryChange();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:run()">
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your code could look like something like this (not tested):

```js
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1001px)');
function mediaQueryChange(mediaQuery)
{
    if (mediaQuery.matches) var t = (0, s.qs)(".js-twitter-feed");
    if ("undefined" != typeof twitterFeed && t) {
        t.classList.remove("u-hide");
        var r = document.createElement("div");
        r.innerHTML = '<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/'.concat(twitterFeed, '">Tweets by ').concat(twitterFeed, "</a>"), t.appendChild(r), (0, o.loadScript)("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js")
    }
};
mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', mediaQueryChange);
mediaQueryChange(mediaQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it also possible to achieve without a HTML body change?

Comment: by the way, the best way to ask a question here would be the way I've written my answer - with a minimal, yet complete code sample that is easy to run and test

Comment: Your new suggestion shows an error message (try to run it).

Comment: Issue solved by removing "mediaQuery" in line 2 (brackets)